# How to export workbook to new excel workbook, but keep original file open

Tags: vba, excel

How do I export an open workbook to a new workbook, while keeping the originally opened workbook open? I believe this is related to my using the .saveAs function, is there another way of exporting a workbook so I can keep the original workbook open?

```
Sub exportXLS()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

answer = MsgBox("Do you want to export to Excel?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Export to Excel")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        Call reportR
        Call reportS
        Sheet27.Calculate
        MyFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Year(Now()) & " - " & Format(Month(Now()), "00"), "Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", , "Save As XLSM file")
        If MyFileName <> "False" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        End If
    End If
end sub()
```

Comment: Tried `SaveCopyAs` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams that works. thank you.